# GCP support proxy protocol V2

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

We need to use the **proxy protocol V2** on GCP and we were not able to find the way to do it.
Any idea if its supported? if yes, how we can do it?

Something similar to this configuration on AWS
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html#proxy-protocol

Comment: Can you elaborate on "what is proxy protocol v2"?

Comment: @Kolban - please have a look at https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/proxy-protocol.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud TCP Proxy Load Balancers support **Proxy Protocol Version 1**.

Version 2 is not supported at this time.

Refer to the documentation for supported versions in this command:

[gcloud compute target-tcp-proxies create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/target-tcp-proxies/create)

Also documented in the REST API:

[Method: targetTcpProxies.setProxyHeader](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/targetTcpProxies/setProxyHeader#request-body)

Comment: Thanks a lot 1+, is there something/anything that we can do to enable it?  I mean use some operator, software to enable it? or the only option is to wait until it will be supported

Comment: @bredstraruts 1) No, there are no flags or setting to set. 2) Check Google's Issue Tracker to see if there is an existing feature request: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers. If there is one, you can vote for the feature and track progress. Otherwise, you can create a new feature request and then wait. If you have an account manager, he/she can get more information for you if there is any.

Comment: 3) Sometimes new features are released to customers by invitation only. Make yourself known via the Issue Tracker. A PM might reach out to you.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot!, one last question, we need only the support the XFF https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#x-forwarded-for , is it possible somehow on GCP? I mean anything that we can do to support it,I ask it again as for us it kind of blocker :-( and we want to find some alternatives if there any

Comment: @bredstraruts Yes, X-Forward-For is supported by default. Your backend just needs to process the HTTP headers.

Comment: Could you please provide an reference? as for AWS we were able to use it only when our back-end support it and we enable the V2 protocol, in GCP it work differently ? does V1 support it?

Comment: I found this, https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#target-proxies but not sure what does it mean external or regional external load balancer

Comment: In most cases, you should use a global HTTP(S) Load Balancer. Here is a link showing that the X-Forwarded-For is supported: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/features#ip_addresses

Comment: Thanks, in the docs I see that its not enabled by default, https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tcp/setting-up-tcp#proxy-protocol am I missing something ?

Comment: Your link is to the TCP Load Balancer. The TCP Load Balancer supports Proxy Version 1 which is not the same thing as Layer 7 X-Forwarded-For.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the docs is a bit confusing, (to me at least) can you please provide the docs that describe the L7 proxy and how to create it?

Comment: You mean HTTP(S) Load Balancer. https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https If you have more questions, create a new post.